# gui for subversion with kde (kdesvn?)

Tags: kde, subversion

I am used to kdesvn. I installed a new ubuntu and kdesvn seems to be unavailable here. Is there a way to get it? If not what kind of gui should I use instead for subversion?

Comment: I know this is somehow the opposite of what you're asking, but just as an opinion, you will be better off getting used to the CLI interface. Just my two cents.

Comment: CLI = command line? Well it is good to see in colour which files changed and so on.

Comment: `colordiff`.  can be used as a drop-in substitute for `diff` (e.g. run `colordiff -u file1 file2` instead of `diff -u file1 file2`).  command-line compatible with `diff`.  It also works if you just pipe `diff`'s output into it (e.g. `svn diff ..... | colordiff`).   you can pipe `colordiff`'s output into `less -R` to see the colours in `less` too.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache search svn client` on my debian system came up with `rapidsvn`.  It's probably available on `ubuntu` too.

```
Package: rapidsvn
Version: 0.12.1dfsg-3.1
Description-en: GUI client for Subversion
 Rapidsvn is a graphical client for the Subversion revision control system
 (svn) providing an easy to use interface for Subversion features. It aims
 to be simple for beginners but flexible enough to increase productivity for
 experienced Subversion users.
Homepage: http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/
```

Interestingly, the `apt-cache search` also showed that `kdesvn` is packaged for debian.  I'm kind of surprised it's not packaged for ubuntu too...maybe it's in a repo you haven't enabled?

Comment: confirmed, rapidsvn is available on ubuntu as well.

Comment: Web searches indicated that kdesvn was in ubuntu till 13 something. Do you know which repository I have to enable? Is there an easy way to add repositories? Sorry for asking silly questions , I am new to ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: i googled a little but wasn't even able to find a ppa for it (doesn't mean there isn't one).  I did find a github repository with kdesvn source code + debian/ubuntu packaging - if you installed `git-buildpackage` and whatever build-dependencies it has (cmake, debhelper, gettext, kdelibs5, libssl-dev, libsvn-dev, and pkg-kde-tools - probably needs at least build-essential too), it would be fairly easy to build a local package and install it with `dpkg -i`.  https://github.com/centic9/kdesvn-ppa

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more GUI clients for Linux:

1. Free software

   - RabbitVCS: http://rabbitvcs.org/
   - PySVN Workbench: http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/
2. Non-free software

   - SmartSVN: http://www.smartsvn.com/